# "Tap & swipe line to travel" annoying message of Google Maps iOS Streetview

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am opening Google StreetView from my app, and I want to just to rotate/look around in the opened Streetview but suddenly some annoying black screen appears with white message saying "Tap & swipe line to travel".

The message seems to be not dismissable, so the Streetview functionality is (also thanks to appearing of it) broken.

If I hit the "back" icon on the top left, I am going back to normal map, not dismissing the message.

You can see the [video of the problem here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBAHz4_m-W0&feature=youtu.be).

Anyone has clue why is this shit happening? I am just swiping normally around the screen..

Sometimes it appears right after opening Streetview.

Comment: Found out that issue was already logged in 
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9988. Just wait for any update :)

Comment: Good, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using Google SDK to load steetview.That works perfectly for me and I can open it in my own app instead of leaving my app. But if google doesn't have any panorama image for that specific latitude and longitude, then it's a different thing. But you should try to using Google SDK to load streetview in your app and see if it makes any difference.

You can use cocoapods to add 'GoogleMaps' sdk.